# In Batch: Read only the folder file name from a directory

Tags: batch-file, dos, filenames

I have the following batch script to print all the folders under a directory

```
for /d %X in (c:\web\*) do echo %X
```

and it prints out

```
c:\web\folder1
c:\web\folder2
....
```

Can i change the batch script and remove the path and only prints out folder name?

```
folder1
folder2
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for /d %F in (c:\web\*) do echo %~nxF
```

See also `for /?`.  The `n` says "just the filename" and the `x` says "just the extension," in case you've got directory names containing a period.